# How to stop VS2017 preparing the docker images

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I use VS2017 (15.7) with Win10 (1803) and Docker (18.03).
My solution contains a Docker-Project (dcproj) which defines how my docker container should start.

Whenever I open Visual Studio or change code it automatically starts preparing the container.

`========== Preparing Containers ==========
Getting Docker containers ready...
<snip>
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
<snip>
Successfully built cbde0ec28022
<snip>
Done!  Docker containers are ready.`

How can I stop that behavior? It eats up the performance of my laptop!
When I want to start the container I would start, but building all the time is too much.

Is there a setting for this?

Issue Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/100

Answer (score 7):

The solution is by disabling it under

`Tools->Options menu and then Container Tools->Settings`

Comment: Which exactly setting is it? I don't see any matching setting, but I'm on VS2019...

Answer (score 3):

To clarify SeriousM's answer, the exact setting is:

> Tools -> Options... -> Container Tools ->
> Single Project -> Run containers on project open.

You may also want to change the same setting in:

> [..] -> Container Tools -> Docker Compose.

This also applies to VS 2019 and 2022.